# Create tree like structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I have a reference to an object in javascript? I have the following code:

```
// define nodes
var NodeA = new Object();
var NodeB = new Object();

NodeA = {
    name: "A",
    children: [
        NodeB
    ]
}

NodeB = {
    name: "B",
    children: []
};

var test = NodeA.children[0].name;
// How can I make test = "A" ???  <----------------
alert(test);
```

I know that if I create NodeB before creating NodeA it will solve my problem.

Comment: `NodeB` does resolve to a reference to an object but you are creating a completely new object with `NodeB = {...}` (and happen to assign it to the same variable). Variables and values are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign properties to `NodeB` instead of setting `NodeB` to be a reference to a entirely new object:

```js
var NodeB = {};

var NodeA = {
    name: "A",
    children: [
        NodeB
    ]
}

Object.assign( NodeB, {
    name: "B",
    children: []
} );

var test = NodeA.children[0].name;
alert(test);
```

Note that for Internet Explorer of `Object.assign` support you would need to use the [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).
You could also just assign the properties to the existing object instead of using object literal notation to create a new one:

```js
var NodeB = {};

var NodeA = {
    name: "A",
    children: [
        NodeB
    ]
}

NodeB.name = "B";
NodeB.children = [];

var test = NodeA.children[0].name;
alert(test);
```

Comment: Should it be: `Object.assign`?? You put a comma there by mistake I think.

Comment: Note that [`.assign`'s compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility) on browsers isn't that great at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a function constructor:

```js
function Node(name) {
    this.name = name,
    this.children = [];
}

var nodeA = new Node('A'),
    nodeB = new Node('B');

nodeA.children.push(nodeB);

document.write(nodeA.children[0].name);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(nodeA, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Nina, what's the difference? If you then assign a new value to `nodeB`, `nodeA.children` won't change.

Comment: @isvforall, if you assign a value to a variable, tha last value/reference is lost. or do i miss something?

Comment: OP change the `NodeB` *after* constructing the `NodeA.children`, if you change the `NodeB`(assign a new value) you will have the same affect as OP

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a new value you are removing the reference of the object and then you cannot access to the object that inside `children` array

```
NodeB = {
    name: "B",
    children: []
};
```

You can use `dot` notation to assign a new properties:

```
NodeB.name = "B";
NodeB.children = [];
```

Example:

```js
var NodeA = new Object();
var NodeB = new Object();

NodeA = {
    name: "A",
    children: [
        NodeB
    ]
}

NodeB.name = "B";
NodeB.children = [];

var test = NodeA.children[0].name;

alert(test);
```